# Python XML Parser to iterate specific tags

Tags: python, xml-parsing

Here is how my XML data look like

xml_data

```xml
<Attributes>
    <value>
        <country name = "America" >
            <Info> This is the info of America </Info>
            <State name = Missouri>
                <Info> This is the info of Missouri </Info>
                <population number = "50"  area = "1000 > </population>
            <State name = Texas>
                <Info> This is the info of Texas </Info>
                <population number = "60"  area = "2000 > </population>
        </country>   
        <country name = "India" >
            <Info> This is the info of India </Info>
            <State name = UP>
                <Info> This is the info of UP </Info>
                <population number = "150"  area = "3000 > </population>
            <State name = TG>
                <Info> This is the info of TG </Info>
                <population number = "30"  area = "500 > </population>
        </country>           
    </value>
</Attributes>
```

I want the output from my python program as below

```
America Missouri  50  1000
America Texas     60  2000
India   UP        150 3000
India   UP        30  500
```

I have written the below code but not satisfied as I'm looping thru each and every tag and storing the values.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml_value = ET.fromstring(xml_data)
for line in xml_value.iter():
    if line.tag == 'country':
       country_name = line.attrib['name']
    elif line.tag == 'State':
        st_name = line.attrib['name']
    elif line.tag == 'population':
       print(country_name, st_name, line.attrib['number'], line.attrib['area']))
```

Is there a way where I can Iterate directly to the Country tag, then to State and to population, instead of going to Info tags ?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your XML is not well formed, because your State-tag doesn't have a closed tag!